# The requested URL "http://localhost:8000/" cannot be found or is not available. Please check the spelling or try again later

Tags: apache

I installed Apache on my laptop with Windows 7. But when I try to verify the installation I get the following message:

The requested URL  cannot be found or is not available. Please check the spelling or try again later.

I tried modifying the httpd.conf file by changing the listing port to: 80,81,85 and 8000 but nothing worked.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you (re-)started apache after making the configuration changes?

Comment: I don't even see the Apache service under "services" through the admin tools.

Comment: have you tried using WAMP? also make sure nothing is using the port, i know skype does and i had that issue before

Comment: I installed WAMP and still had the same problem. The root cause was that port 80 was being used but it wasn't being used by SKYPE and I had no applications running. I found out in YOUTUBE that what blocks or uses port 80 could be SQL SERVER. I had to stop all the SQL Server services that were running (in the background) and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I installed WAMP and still had the same problem. The root cause was that port 80 was being used but it wasn't being used by SKYPE and I had no applications running. I found out in YOUTUBE that what blocks or uses port 80 could be SQL SERVER. I had to stop all the SQL Server services that were running (in the background) and that solved the issue.